# Split by period ignore few cases

Tags: c#, regex

I am splitting a string with a period and space(". "), I want to split with a ". " but ignore if it matches few patterns like MR. , JR. , [oneletter]. , Dr. 
Pattern list is static.(case insensitive)

Examples:

1) My Name is MR. ABC and working for XYZ.

Output: No split. Just one line

2) My Name is Mr. ABC. I work for XYZ.

Output: string[0] = My Name is Mr. ABC.
        string[1] = I work for XYZ.

3) My Name is ABC. I work for XYZ.

Output: string[0] = My Name is ABC.
        string[1] = I work for XYZ.

4) My Name is MR. ABC Jr. DEF. I work for XYZ.

Output: string[0] = My Name is MR. ABC Jr. DEF. (MR. and Jr. are ignoring cases )
        string[1] = I work for XYZ.

Comment: Your regex would go something like this `(?<!A|B|C|D)\.(?!E|F|G|H)`

Comment: Thanks for the response @sln. "Case with WORD. Another Sentence " will not work

Comment: Example # 3 you give fails the single character test

Comment: in fact, so does #2

Comment: My Bad I changed my example.

Answer (score 1):

Using sln's regex pattern here's a mock up of how it should work

```
                    List<string> ignores = new List<string>(){ "MR", "MS", "MRS", "DR", "PROF" };

        ignores = ignores.Select(x => @"\b" + x).ToList();

        string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        foreach (char letter in alphabet.ToCharArray())
        {
            ignores.Add(@"\b" + letter);
        }

        string test = "This is a test for Prof. Plum. Here is a test for Ms. White. This is A. Test. Welcome to GMR. Next Line.";

        string regexPattern = $@"(?<!{string.Join("|", ignores)})\.\s";

        string[] results = Regex.Split(test, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

results are the 3 sentences (though you need to re-add the . to the end of all but the last value)

Edited to add all single character ignores

Edited to only account for whole words on ignore list

Comment: Thanks @Broom. I tested with  "Welcome to GMR. Next Line." this case is failing.

Comment: ah, I understand why, its the MR at the end of GMR, one sec and I'll edit to account for this

Comment: Yes. If I add space to ignore list (like new List<string>(){ " MR", " MS", " MRS", " DR", " PROF" };). GMR Case is covered but When line starts with "MR. ABC works for XYZ" it fails.

Comment: @cubcoder00 ok, I swapped the \s for \b which matches word boundaries instead of spaces

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Broom. It worked
(Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score)